# How many commits get rolledback when we call rollback?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

What is the behavior of rollback when we have 2 or more commits?

```
Connection conn= getConnection();

try{

doSomeInsertOrUpdateStep1(conn); //some sql update/insert using connection
conn.commit(); //step 1

doSomeInsertOrUpdateStep2(conn); //some sql update/insert using connection
conn.commit(); //step 2

//ERROR IS THROWN HERE AFTER SECOND COMMIT
} catch(Exception e){

   conn.rollback(); //what will be rolledback exactly step 1 or step2 or both?

}
```

If there is an error thrown after the second commit, I don't know what is expected to be rolled back in this scenario.

Comment: `rollback` should be issued before `commit` any time. Otherwise has no sense.

Comment: When you commit something, a rollback will not impact it. A rollback is used to undo work that has not yet been committed. So it really depends on when your exception is thrown.

Comment: I updated with the position of the error, after the second commit.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan how rollback should be used before commit? what is it gonna rollback then if nothing is committed?

Comment: Please refer to the above comment of @Todd which's really helpful, and nicely explained.

Comment: You can't rollback a commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm) :

> Use the COMMIT statement to end your current transaction and make permanent all changes performed in the transaction.
>
> [...]
>
> Until you commit a transaction: [...] You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with the ROLLBACK statement.

So basically your code works as follows :

- run the first query : if it succeeds, then COMMIT it and continue ; else ROLLBACK (revert any uncommitted changes done before the first statement was executed) and stop (do not run the next statement)
- run the second statement : if it succeeds then COMMIT, else ROLLBACK. Please note that, since a COMMIT was executed just before executing the statement, there will be nothing to ROLLBACK anyway.

I think the this logic can maybe be optimized. From my understanding, you might be looking to *run both queries in a single transaction* meaning : either both queries succeed and you want to COMMIT them, or if any fails and you want to ROLLBACK everything.

To implement that behavior, you would need to remove the first COMMIT (after the first query was executed successfully).

Comment: thanks, just to clarify, Case1: if a commit is successful and we then do a rollback, rollback will be meaningless since commit is completed. Case2, if an exception happens during commit and we catch and rollback, then rollback undoes changes happened by this commit. It is a little bit confusing to me, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedAbouhegaza... COMMIT do not generate errors, excepted in rare cases ; INSERT/UPDATES are usually more likely to generate errors, and I guess that’s what your code intends to handle. But, to respond your question, if a COMMIT itself fails then it means data could not be saved ; it will be trapped and a ROLLBACK will happen, which will undo all uncommitted changes until that point.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when the exception occurs.

For example, if an exception is thrown after the first commit and before the second commit, the rollback would undo any DB updates performed by `doSomeInsertOrUpdateStep2(conn);`.

If, on the other hand, an exception is thrown before the first commit, the rollback of the catch block would undo any DB updates performed by `doSomeInsertOrUpdateStep1(conn);` (and in this case `doSomeInsertOrUpdateStep2(conn);` won't be executed at all).

Any updates that were already committed will not be rolled back.

Comment: @AhmedAbouhegaza if the exception is thrown after the second commit, nothing will be rolled back (assuming the code that throws the exception didn't make any DB updates)

Comment: Actually the scenario is that some changes were made to the DB in both commits, and an error is thrown at or after the second commit, what will rollback rolls? commit 1 changes or commit 2 changes or both? Thanks

Comment: @AhmedAbouhegaza the changes of commit1 will not be rolled back, since you say that commit didn't fail. If the exception was thrown during the second commit, all the changes made after the first commit will be rolled back. If it was thrown after the second commit, any changes made after the second commit will be rolled backed.

Comment: are you saying that a failed commit doesn't rollback automatically? and if so what is the use of rollback then? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AhmedAbouhegaza a failed commit may rollback automatically. I'm not sure about that. Either way, the explicit rollback would cancel any uncommitted changes that haven't been cancelled already.

Comment: @AhmedAbouhegaza - are you getting an exception *from* the second commit itself; or just in code you haven't shown after that commit has happened? It might help to include the actual exception in in your question. If the commit doesn't succeed because, say, deferred constraints aren't met then you are left with uncommitted changes, so those would be rolled back by your explicit `rollback()`. If the commit was OK then your rollback does nothing. As has been said already, "it depends".